# visual studio 2015 console does not wait for key

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, io

Using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>,  the program finishes and the console closes without waiting for input. I cannot use

```
int tmp;
cin>>tmp;
```

I had ticked an option in VS2013 which makes the console wait for a key, but I can't find it in VS2015.

Comment: `Ctrl+F5` works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that the project has the "SubSystem" property set to "Console". This can be found in the project properties under Linker > System.

Comment: Is there a generic solution for all projects?